# remote login to slave from master

Tags: ssh, connection

ssh slave

permission denied(public key)

the above line is an error msg when i m tryin to login to slave from master node..
what is the problem any anyone tel.??

Comment: StackOverflow is a website targeted at **professional software developers**.  If you are not sure about what StackOverflow is or how to behave here, please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).   If you wish to get good answers, you **must** ask good, on-topic questions.  I would **strongly** suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/1228) for hints.  Also, re-asking the same question over and over is considered abuse of the system.  Please don't do that again.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you haven't setup key exchange on the slave.  You can find a tutorial here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Note that you will need access to the slave machine to complete this, so you will need to either physically use the machine or have the sysadmin do it for you.